# Json response as tooltip value lookup for a jquery sparklines graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sparklines

I'm trying to use a json response as the **tooltipValueLookups** parameter in a [sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline) graph, without success. The tooltip just keeps showing 0:5 and 1:8 instead of Mulder:5 and Scully:8

It works perfectly if I just declare the variable **agents** with the exactly same json:

```
var agents = {"names":{"0":"Mulder", "1":"Scully"}}
```

But evrything goes south when I try to do it with the server response, as intended. Could anyone tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

```
var agents = $.ajax({
    url     : "/ajaxAgents",
    type    : "get",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Response: {"names":{"0":"Mulder", "1":"Scully"}}

```
$("#mini-chart").sparkline([5,8], {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '30px',
    barWidth: 6,
    barSpacing: 2,
    barColor: '#0aa699',
    tooltipFormat: '<span style="color: {{color}}">&#9679;</span> {{offset:offset}}: {{value}}',
    tooltipValueLookups:{offset:agents.names},
    negBarColor: '#0aa699'});
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After a lot of coffee and swearing, I finally got it to work. Not a very elegant solution, I must admit.

First, I had to change the server-side php function to return a **string**, rather than json.

Then in the ajax call:

```
var response = $.ajax({
    url     : "/ajaxAgents",
    type    : "get",
    dataType: 'text',
    global  : false,
    async   : false,
    success : function(data){return data;}
}).responseText;
```

Then, parse the response and filter it:

```
var agents = $.parseJSON(response);
var filteredNames = $.map(agents.names, function(el) {
        return el;
    });
```

And finally, the sparklines function:

```
    $("#mini-chart").sparkline(agentsData, {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '30px',
    barWidth: 6,
    barSpacing: 2,
    barColor: '#0aa699',
    tooltipFormat: '<span style="color: {{color}}">&#9679;</span> {{offset:offset}}: {{value}}',
    tooltipValueLookups:{offset:filteredNames},
    negBarColor: '#0aa699'});
```

@Hüseyin: Thanks for your assistance, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Filter json with [$.grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var filteredNames = $.map(agents.names, function(el, i) {
    return el;
});
```

And use in your function like;

```
tooltipValueLookups:{offset: filteredNames}
```

You can see demo here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwmyw/1/)**

**Note:** If you are returning string from server, you need to use;

```
var agents = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I can't redeclare json, it is the response from the server. Also, I'm pretty sure the **tooltipValueLookups** option **must** have the keys. Like I said, the funcion works like a charm if I directly declare the JSON object. Things go wrong when I try to use the response, which is exactly as expected. Thanks, anyway :)

Comment: @Sam, ok json can be remain same. I have updated my code and demo, see my updated asnwer.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. parseJSON is returning null, which kind of makes sense, since json is already an object. And mapping agent.names throws a TypeError. Thanks again for your reply, @Hüseyin.

Comment: But, it is already object, so do not use json parse. use it directly. And see if it works

Comment: I did test parsing directly. It was throwing an error **TypeError**, couldn't figure out why. Anyways, I found a solution. I edited the question with the solution I found. Thanks :)